# WMI Filters for specific group

Tags: windows, networking, wmi, samba, group-policy

Today I tried to create a WMI filter for a GPO to *exclude* a specific group, for which the GPO should not apply.

I used a WQL like this:
Select * from Win32_Group where SID != 'S-1-5-32-544-whatever-555'

However, it didn't work.
The corresponding output of the query looks correct in the "WMI multi Query" tool from Tools4Net.

I'm new to WMI:
When creating a WMI I just need to copy the WQL in the query field, right?

What I want to achieve:
Terminal Users on a server should get kicked out, when they are inactive for more than 6 hours. However, certain users should never get kicked.
Is there an easy way to do that?